# How to create and populate the wso2 db tables when using docker-compose?

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to create a test deployment of the wso2 products using docker-compose, starting with the API manager. I'm using the Dockerfile https://hub.docker.com/r/wso2/wso2am. I have configured my master datasource to point to a PostgreSQL server that is managed by docker-compose.

I have an initial script that is run in the pgsql container that creates the database and db user.

I dont know how to get the wso2 API Manager to create and populate the tables. The wso2 documentation say to use the "-DSETUP" when running the product but I dont have a access to this.

Does anyone know how to do this? Or so I need to build and configure my own Docker images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-DSetup is now deprecated and it is not available in the latest product releases. Please check the docker-compose resources of WSO2 API Manager in [1].

In this docker-compose example, it has used Mysql and Mysql supports giving sql files for database creation when starting the container. I guess in Postgresql, you can do the same. Otherwise, need to automate the database table creation.

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/tree/v3.0.0.1/docker-compose/apim-with-analytics